# Webpack не транспиирует typescript в es5

Tags: typescript, webpack

Собираю приложение на js и ts с помощью webpack. И ts-loader выдаёт ошибку при сборке.

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently
> no loaders are configured to process this file.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл typescript.ts

```
let b: Array<number>;
b = [];

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (const i of b) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: ['./typescript.ts'],
    output: {
      filename: 'main.es5.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  '@babel/preset-env',
                  {
                    targets: {
                      browsers: [
                        '> 1%',
                        'last 2 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'ie 11',
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        }, {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              compilerOptions: {
                transpileOnly: true,
                noImplicitAny: true,
                noEmitOnError: true,

                module: 'es6',
                target: 'es5',
                allowJs: true,
                checkJs: true,
              },
            },
          },
          include: '/',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
  };
```

Comment: у вас не закавычено `exclude: /node_modules/`. а по теме: возможно проблема в настройках tsconfig.json

Comment: @nörbörnën оно и не должно быть в кавычках, это регулярное выражение

Comment: @andreymal уух, вона оно чо, михалыч. тогда просто tsconfig.json показать

Comment: @nörbörnën фраза "no loaders are configured" вызывает у меня подозрение, что до tsconfig.json дело даже не успело дойти. Хотя лоадеры вроде прописаны верно...

Comment: Если дело происходит в Windows, то возможно стоит стереть `include: '/'` так как в Windows абсолютные пути не могут начинаться с слэша

Comment: @andreymal я прогнал эту сборку у себя на под макос, могу сказать что на unix-like системе собирается

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему переносом параметров для TS в отдельный файл.
В файле webpack.config.js указал:

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        configFile: 'tsconfig.es5.json',
      },
    },
}
```

А в файле tsconfig.es5.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
    }
}
```

И всё заработало. Подозреваю, что без файла многие параметры по-умолчанию не подключаются.

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы просто убрали include и поэтому заработало (если у вас Windows)